# Synonymize or merge [flux-influxdb] and [fluxlang]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both of the [flux-influxdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux-influxdb) tag and the [fluxlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluxlang) tag are used for the same reason : the flux language made by InfluxData.

**Some information :**
The [flux-influxdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux-influxdb) tag has no usage guidance, but it has a tag wiki, and 54 questions. It's 9 months old
The [fluxlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fluxlang) tag has both a usage guidance and a tag wiki and 12 questions. It was made more than 2 years ago.
Both of them somewhat active.

I don't know if they should be made synonymous, or just simply merged, as both of them don't appear as suggestions when adding tags.